# how to save a single character from a string into an NSDictionary Object

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have defined a const char in my header like so

```
const char *storageIcon;

@property (assign) const char *storageIcon;
```

I have a string value in my dictionay that is a single Character, I am woundering is the code below the right way about placing it into my variable?

```
storageIcon = [[tempDict valueForKey:@"STORAGEICON"] UTF8String];
```

The thing is that later on this element becomes corrupted.. almost like a memory leak is ccuring and I cannot figure out whats going wrong.

Any help / tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for `NSString UTF8String`:

> The returned C string is automatically freed just as a returned object would be released; you should copy the C string if it needs to store it outside of the autorelease context in which the C string is created.

You are assigning this "soon to be freed" C-string pointer to an assigned property. Basically the value is lost right away.

You can either make proper use of `malloc` and `free` with the property's setter and getter methods or you make things a lot easier and change the property to be an `NSString` instead of a `const char *`.

Any client of the property that needs an actual C-string can call the `UTF8String` method as needed.

One other thing. The title of you question talks about a single character. The would be `char`, not `char *`. If you really just want the first character of the `NSString`, then you need a different approach than what you are doing now.

Comment: okay.. cool that makes sense now that you say it. Thanks for the help! going to give it ago now